# Reflection with T4 get assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection, t4

I want to get all of class in the specific assembly this is my code

```
 var assembly=Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

 var assemblies = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, "RepoLib.Rts.Web.Plugins.Profiler.Models", StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToArray();
```

when c# code all thing is ok and i get my assemblies but when write in `t4` file i dont have any error but my assemblies count is.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In a T4 template the executing assembly is not yours but one from the T4 engine.

To access types from your assemblies, you have to perform the following steps:

1. Add a reference to your assembly to the template. Put that at the top of it:

   ```
   <#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)<Project>\bin\Debug\<Project>.dll" #>
   ```
2. Import the namespace of your assembly. Put that somewhere below the previous line:

   ```
   <#@ import namespace="<Project>.<Namespace>" #>
   ```
3. To access the types in this assembly, pick one of them and get the assembly from it:

   ```
   var assembly = typeof(<Type in assembly>).Assembly;
   var types = assembly.GetTypes()
                       .Where(t => String.Equals(
                           t.Namespace,
                           "RepoLib.Rts.Web.Plugins.Profiler.Models",
                           StringComparison.Ordinal))
                       .ToArray();
   ```

Comment: What is <Type in assembly>?

Comment: @ShahroozJefri: Any type in the assembly you want to get all types from. For example, it could be one of the types in the `RepoLib.Rts.Web.Plugins.Profiler.Models` namespace

Comment: If you're not using preprocessed templates and you want to get information about the types and classes inside the same project as your T4 template resides, I would advise against using Reflection. T4 templates are transformed at design time, so the assembly referenced by $(SoutionDir)<Project>\bin\Debug\<Project>.dll may be from your last build and outdated!
You might want to use the Visual Studio Code Model (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134016/design-time-reflection/14402269#14402269)

Comment: How can you do this without type of?