# How to include assembly in T4 template of asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, t4

In my Text Template i'm declaring my text template as follows

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cshtml" #>

<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.ObjectModel" #>
   <#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\MvcTemplateApplication\bin\Debug\MvcTemplateApplication.Dll" #>
 <#@import namespace="MvcTemplateApplication"#>
```

In above it gives following error

```
Metadata file could not be found
```

how to include project dll of application in above text template ?

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this needs to be done, but we have struggled with this issue also, and the following differences i could see:

We don't mix the `assembly`- and `import`-Tags, so we have always a group of assembly tags and then the import tags. Like so:

```
<#@ output extension="gevasys.generated.cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly name="System.Data.Linq.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly name="$(TargetPath)"#> // our own assembly
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
```

Secondly we don't import our own DLL-Namespaces instead we reference the class with the full namespace in front of it. Like so:

```
var xy = new Company.NS1.NS2.MyOwnClass( );
```

Maybe this can help you also.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the assembly you're referencing has been built. Sounds strange, but T4 templates are transformed at design time. That means, if the project you're trying to reference hasn't been built or you have cleaned the solution before, there's no .dll at "$(SolutionDir)\MvcTemplateApplication\bin\Debug\MvcTemplateApplication.Dll.

Secondly the MvcTemplateApplication.dll might be outdated! You're referencing the last successful build, which may not include the last changes!

If you want generate code based on the classes of your project, I recommend you use the Visual Studio Automation Code Model. See my answer to this SO question: [Design Time Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134016/design-time-reflection/14402269#14402269)